# SCP fails to authenticate due to backslash in username

Tags: scp

I am using SCP to transfer a folder from a remote server (RS1) to another remote server (RS2). My command is:

```
scp PEM\username@RS1:/home/local/PEM/folderName1/ PEM\username@RS2:/home/local/PEM/foldername2
```

Final errors I get after putting the password for `PEM\username` is:

> Permission denied, please try again
> Permission denied, please try again
> Received disconnect from RS2. Too many authentication failures for **PEMusername**

As you can see, the error message quotes `PEMusername` as my username and not `PEM\username`.

Is there a way to explicitly mention the username for SCP protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` is an escape character in *nix shell.

If you need to specify backslash explicitly, either double it:

```
scp PEM\\username@RS1:/home/local/PEM/folderName1/ ...
```

or wrap whole parameter to single-quotes:

```
scp 'PEM\username@RS1:/home/local/PEM/folderName1/' ...
```