# How to escape a # username in ~/.ssh/config file

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

I am on macos monterey & have the following in my ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host foo
  HostName cyberark.company.com
  User user@user#company.com@target_vm
```

`ssh foo` from my terminal has `#company.com@target_vm` portion of my User value automatically truncated where as `ssh user@user#company.com@target_vm@cyberark.company.com` works correctly.  Seems like everything after # is treated as comments in .ssh/config file.  How do I escape # in this file?

Answer (score 0):

From [SSH Config documentation](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/config#format-of-ssh-client-config-file-ssh_config) the character `#` is a special character interpreted by ssh:

> Empty lines and lines starting with '#' are comments.

You can prevent these behavior from happening by telling explicitly ssh to read litteral characters instead of interpreting them:

- using backslash escape character `\` special characters such as `#` and `@`  (more informations [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html))
- flanking the whole string with quotes `'`

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058713/scp-error-due-to-backslash-in-username) from [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl)

Here you may want to try the following in your case:

```
Host foo
  HostName cyberark.company.com
  User 'user@user#company.com@target_vm'
```

or using backslash:

```
Host foo
  HostName cyberark.company.com
  User user\@user\#company.com\@target_vm
```